# Google Sheets 'order by' messed up by headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm simply wanting to query 5 columns of data from 'Raw Paste' sheet, and then reorder them.

```
=QUERY('Raw Paste'!A:E, "select A, B, C, D, E order by B asc")
```

The problem is it appears the headers are messing it up (0 results)... if I do `!A2:E900` it works but the problem is if I try to select "max" range it goes back to 0 results, which makes that useless if it can't just select ALL the rows without having to adjust `900` to fit whatever the data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('Raw Paste'!A:E, "select A,B,C,D,E order by B", 0)
```

or if you have headers:

```
=QUERY('Raw Paste'!A:E, "select A,B,C,D,E order by B", 1)
```

if you still got first rows empty you will need to include `where` like:

```
=QUERY('Raw Paste'!A:E, "select A,B,C,D,E where A is not null order by B", 1)
```